# Local assembly not full trust

Tags: .net, .net-assembly, code-access-security, full-trust

How can I find out why a local assembly is not running with full trust?

The problem originated with WCF and proxy [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10797945/157224) but seems to be a CAS problem.

I have local assembly (i.e. C:\Whatever\xxx.exe) where I got an exception

> Insufficient permissions for setting the configuration section
>   'defaultProxy'. Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Net.WebPermission, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

My interpretation is that the assembly is not running with full trust.

Is there a tool that will tell me what policy is restricting the trust level for an assembly?

I have tried `caspol.exe` but it just says:

> 1. All code: Nothing
>      1.1.  Zone - MyComputer: FullTrust
>      ...

Comment: It's definitely a local disk and not a mapped network drive?  Assemblies from network drives aren't given the same policy...

Comment: Yes. I created the folder myself on C: